# ^HV Only returning some values

Tags: rfid, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm trying to print some RFID tags and retrieve their TIDs to store them in my system and know which tags have been printed. Right now I'm reading the TID and sending it back to my computer (connected via USB with the my ZT421 printer) with the following code:

```
^RFR,H,0,12,2^FN0^FS^FH_^HV0,24,,_0D_0A,L^FS
^RFW,H,2,12,1^FD17171999ABABABAAAAAAAAAB^FS
```

This is repeated for each tag that I'm printing. However, when printing 10 tags, I only get 9 TIDs. If after that I try to print 7 tags, I still get 9 TIDs. To be honest I'm a bit lost now, because even trying to use the code examples from the ZPL manual (I've tried the ^RI instruction also) it doesn't seem to work.

The communication with the printer is beeing done through Zebra Setup Utilities' direct communication tool.

I tried to retrieve each printed tag TID with:

```
^RFR,H,0,12,2^FN0^FS^FH_^HV0,24,,_0D_0A,L^FS
^RFW,H,2,12,1^FD17171999ABABABAAAAAAAAAB^FS
```

but I always get 9 TIDs.

I also tried getting the TID with the ZPL manual example for the ^RI command:

```
^XA
^FO20,120^A0N,60^FN0^FS
^RI0,,5^FS
^HV0,,Tag ID:^FS
^XZ
```

And I got absolutely nothing returned to the computer, just a mssage saying "Tag ID:" and no value shown.

I would really appreciate some help with this...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue, but I'm going to leave the solution here just in case someone else is facing the same problem.

I thought that maybe it wasn't a code issue, but something related to the computer-printer communication. It turned out to be the case. The Zebra Setup Utilities program has a button that says "options". If you click it, a new screen will open and there you can configure the seconds that the program will wait for the printer response (in this case through USB). By default it's set to 5, i changed this value to 100, which is the maximum. This meant that instead of just printing and retrieving the TIDs of 6-9 tags, now I can do it for about 100.

This is not amazing because in my case it implied creating 25 files for the 2500 tags I had to print and store the TIDs, however it's far better than before.